# Creating a datatime with timezone in python 3.7+?

Tags: python, timezone, python-3.7, python-datetime

I'm trying to create a datetime object with an end goal to create a series of date times by the hour for multiple years for a given time zone.

What function does this?

I tried 
     datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo="Canada/Mountain")

How would I go set the day time to daylight saving Canadian/Mountian time?

Comment: did you try with `pytz`?

Comment: I'm new to python and pytz seemed to be recommended. The data. I'm downloading does not handle daylight savings times well. Double hour endings are handled like 02* and 02. I thought pytz would hendle daylight savings better.

Comment: still I didn't get what you ask @user2946746, can you provide more information please.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve the problem.

```
from dateutil.tz import gettz
datetime(2017, 4, 19, 22, 33, tzinfo=gettz("Europe/Madrid"))
datetime(2017, 4, 19, 22, 33,tzinfo=gettz("Europe/Madrid")) + timedelta(hours=1)

datetime(2017, 4, 19, 22, 0, 
tzinfo=gettz("Canada/Mountain"))
datetime(2017, 4, 19, 22, 0, tzinfo=gettz("Canada/Mountain")) + timedelta(hours=1)
```